# how to show pop up on empty field in form applet in siebel

Tags: siebel

I am trying to show a pop up that if a field in form applet, lets suppose "Firstname" field is empty, soon the applet will load and find if firstname field is empty , it will show an alert message that please update the firstname and when I click on that alert message , a pop up screen will appear which will let user manually enter the first name and that record will store in the database. And when next time user will logon the field will show the firstname. please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: can anybody please answer , atlease give me some hint

Comment: IMHO, you haven't got an answer because this is not the way things are done in Siebel. Your requirement can be very easily done via a runtime event, invoking data validation manager. No scripting required, but there will not be a separate form popup for data entry.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are complicating things around? You can display the error message by placing script in **WebApplet_Load Event** to check if the field is null or not and no need to display another popup applet. User can enter First Name in the form applet you already displaying.